# Geolocation watchPostion firing every second

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

in my Ionic app, I implemented the geolocation watchPosition with the following options.  My options are set to fire every 10 seconds, but its firing every second.  And often it fires two times per second.

```
function watchPosition() {
   var options = {
      maximumAge: 10000,
      timeout: 10000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
   }
   watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

   function onSuccess(pos) {
      ...
   }
   function onError(error) {
      ...
   }
}
```

And when my device is ready, I trigger the watchPosition function with an addListener:

Original call was like this:
    var watchID = null ;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", watchPosition);

I then changed to this:
    `document.addEventListener("deviceready",setupWatch) ;`

```
function setupWatch() {
    // global var here so it can be cleared on logout (or whenever).
    activeWatch = setInterval(watchPosition, 5000);
}
```

And it is still firing every second.

Then I replaced the `addEventListener` simply with, I realized the eventListener was already inside of Ionics `$ionicPlatform.ready() { .. }` thus an eventListener wasn't needed.  However, just calling this now triggers the watchPosition like 5 times per second, not once per 5 seconds.:

```
setupWatch() ;
```

Additional question regarding best practices for watchPosition. What is the ideal timeout for continuing to call this function...is every second OK, is it too much load/processing, does it drain batteries faster, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap, Cordova watchposition fire success every 1 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254420/phonegap-cordova-watchposition-fire-success-every-1-second) And [Geolocation watch doesn't fire consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764217/geolocation-watch-doesnt-fire-consistently)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean please?  Where am I calling it multiple times?  I think with addEventListener, once device is ready, call the function.  Once function is in memory, call itself every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The `timeout` and `maximumAge` you're using are not defining how frequently you have an answer from the browser. Here is what MDN says about these properties:

> `PositionOptions.timeout` Is a positive long value representing the maximum length of time (in milliseconds) the device is allowed to take in order to return a position.
>
> `PositionOptions.maximumAge` Is a positive long value indicating the maximum age in milliseconds of a possible cached position that is acceptable to return.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions#Properties)

I would advice you to store the value from the callback in a variable and user another `setInterval` to return the value at a rate you can define.

**EDIT**

If you want to handle the rate of answer, you can use the function `getCurrentPosition`, that will fire the callback only once ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition))

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what those values were.  I thought `timeout` was the interval at which the function would repeat itself again.  I am wrapping the watchPosition function in a setInterval  now.

Comment: I added the setInterval (updated my code above) and now its calling 5 times per second.

Comment: I think it's good that you call `watchPosition` only once, like you did at the beginning. How do you want to use the result ?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, you can simply change `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and it should work better ;)

Comment: just using getCurrentPosition in setInterval periodically did not work for me, after a very short time, it stopped returning coordinates. Watchposition worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my code the watchPosition was firing twice in succession but the getCurrentPostion always just fires once for obvious reasons.

Solution 1 would be to use getCurrentPosition, and then set a timer to re-check that position X milliseconds later and update as required.

Solution 2 (which I used, for various other reasons) would be to use watchPosition but have the callback double-check that the long/lat has actually changed. If not then ignore the rest of the function. So as an example:

```
var oldlong = "";
var oldlat = "";

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onGpsChangeSuccess,onGpsError,{
   maximumAge: 10000, 
   enableHighAccuracy: false, 
   timeout: 15000 
 }
);

var onGpsChangeSuccess = function(){
    //Watch was triggered...

    if(oldlong != position.coords.longitude && oldlat!=position.coords.longitude){

        //Changes detected
        oldlong = position.coords.longitude;
        oldlat = position.coords.latitude; 
        performTheRestOfYourFunctionHere

   }else{
       //No changes detected
   }
}
```

We shouldn't have to perform this additional check, but if the watcher has a bug then it's better to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised that your successive Lat/Lng readings are identical. Perhaps the "accuracy" meters have varied or one source was GPS and another Telco Tower. Outdoors or indoors?

Regardless I recommend [filtering](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen/blob/master/TravelManagerPolyfill.js) readings as appropriate for your App. Ignoring inaccurate or uninteresting readings is IMHO something ALL GPS Apps have to cater for.